# Can SignalR for ASP.NET Core be self hosted in a Windows exe or a Xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

MS recently released an alpha build of SignalR for ASP.NET Core 2.0. I can't see any doco about whether it can be self hosted in a windows service, which earlier versions of SignalR supported.

Also is it possible to have self hosted in a Xamarin app? Imagine a Xamarin app that is basically a wrapper around a website. The website provides most of the functionality. However, the Xamarin app provides specialised services. The website portion would communicate with the app via websockets, which means the Xamarin form would need to be a SignalR SERVER. I ask this in the same question as the windows exe because it would be a similar model (browser <--> Windows exe vs embedded browser <--> Xamarin app). I have something like this working already (using a HttpListener with self signed certificates) but it only provides one way comms but I really need the two way comms that websockets would provide.

I could possibly get away with a more simple Web Sockets solution but would like to know if SignalR is possible. I plan to use a more traditional browser to IIS hosted SignalR solution in future for certain functions and it would be good if I could keep that consistent with the browser to local service communication I described above.

Comment: I don't know what the limitations/constraints of Xamarin forms are. If you can run Kestrel (or basically an ASP.NET Core web app in Xamarin forms) then you will be able to run SignalR.

Comment: Why wouldn't the app just be a client that connects to the site? I don't see why it needs to be a server since, as you said, communication is two-way.